# SQL Server 2005: Test Table Variable as Scalar

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want to write a procedure in SQL Server 2005 that looks at the most recent entry into a table. If that entry happened more than a week ago I want to create a new entry. If not I want to update the most recent one.

```
DECLARE @MaxVal TABLE (Date DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @MaxVal (Date) 
(SELECT MAX(Date)
FROM schema.TABLE_TO_UPDATE)

IF [@MaxVal].Date > '2013-01-01'
    PRINT 'New entry'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Update the entry'
```

I keep getting the following error message:

> *Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>
>   The multi-part identifier "@MaxVal.Date" could not be bound.*

I've looked up that message, but the most people seem to get it in reference to JOINS. Any idea why it would happen here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IF statement is referencing a column from a table, which can't be done without an associated query.  You can try this instead

```
IF (select [@MaxVal].Date from @MaxVal) > '2013-01-01'
```

This will return the value of your column and compare it to the date constant.